# TCustomADODataSet.FilterOnBookmarks

Tags: delphi, ado

I have an old application which always worked fine. Recently it started to throw EAccessViolation exception in method FilterOnBookmarks. I don't know when it started, maybe when I rebuild it under XE 10.1.

```
procedure TCustomADODataSet.FilterOnBookmarks(Bookmarks: array of const);
var
  I: Integer;
  BookmarkData: OleVariant;
begin
  CheckBrowseMode;
  BookmarkData := VarArrayCreate([Low(Bookmarks), High(Bookmarks)], varVariant);
  for I := Low(Bookmarks) to High(Bookmarks) do
     BookmarkData[I] := POleVariant(TVarRec(Bookmarks[I]).VPointer)^;
  inherited SetFilterText('');
  FFilterGroup := fgUnassigned;
  DestroyLookupCursor;
  try
    Recordset.Filter := BookmarkData; //<---- Here I get EAccessViolation

    First;
    inherited SetFiltered(True);
  except
    inherited SetFiltered(False);
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

I create Bookmarks parameter of FilterOnBookamrks method as an array of TVarRec:

```
type TSQLVarRecArray = array of TVarRec;


PBookmark = ^TBookmark;

TSQLBookmarkList = class(TList)
  private
 ...   
  protected
    function Get(Index: Integer): PBookmark;
  public
...
    procedure Add(Bookmark: TBookmark);
    property Items[Index: Integer]: PBookmark read Get; default;
    function ToVarRecArray: TSQLVarRecArray;
  end;

procedure TSQLBookmarkList.Add(Bookmark: TBookmark);
var PB: PBookmark;
    L: Integer;
begin
  New(PB);
  L := Length(Bookmark);
  SetLength(PB^, L);
  PB^ := Copy(Bookmark, 0, L);
  inherited Add(PB);
end;


function TSQLBookmarkList.ToVarRecArray: TSQLVarRecArray;
var I: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Count);
  for I := 0 to Count - 1 do begin
    Result[I].VType := vtPointer;
    Result[I].Vpointer := Items[I]^;
  end;
end; 




try
  ...
  Arr := BookmarkList.ToVarRecArray;
  FilterOnBookmarks(Arr);
finally
  Arr := nil; //<--- Now I get here EVariantArrayLockedError "Variant or  safe array is locked"
end;
```

This code has been working for years. Has anything changed in 10.1 XE concerning with FilterOnBookmarks, Bookmarks, etc?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in Delphi.
We have the same problem.
See:https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-update/windows-10-update-kb4015217-windows-7-update/d6ee5ee8-a362-48fd-be1d-26a6b6526c34
The problem is in,
C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Common Files \ System \ ado \ msado15.dll
after a recent upgrade.
If you replace msado15.dll with those before the upgrade, the application works well.

Comment: Did you find the solution?
(without app change)
We have the same problem, we can not change the app.
Thank you

Comment: Thank you, @user3648935! Does placing the old version of msado15.dll to the app working directory resolve the problem? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

We temporarily solved the problem.
We replaced msado15.dll in
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files \System \ado
We took msado15.dll from a computer that was not upgraded.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @user3648935!